# How do I recreate the text animation on https://dekks.app

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, web-frontend

[What I am trying to implement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEFWr.gif)

I have tried implementing this with just CSS but what I have been able to achieve is not quite the same. I would include a gif of what I have currently but I'm not able to make it public. But if anything [here](https://codepen.io/kh3996/pen/OJMLOQN) is the codepen link to the approach I utilized and my edit of the code is included below (irrelevant things commented out and "filler text" is used as a placeholder for real text7). I'd be glad if anyone can help me. (To be noted that I'm using Tailwind for most of the styling and I'm only using custom CSS for the animation aspect).

HTML:

```
<div className="loading">
    <div style={{ "--i": "1" }}>
        <span className="text-blue-400 text-40 font-bold">
           Filler Text
        </span>
    </div>
    <div style={{ "--i": "3" }}>
        <span className="text-blue-400 text-40 font-bold">
            Filler Text
        </span>
    </div>
    <div style={{ "--i": "5" }}>
        <span className="text-blue-400 text-40 font-bold">
            Filler Text
        </span>
    </div>
    <div style={{ "--i": "7" }}>
        <span className="text-blue-400 text-40 font-bold">
            Filler Text
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.loading {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    height: 120.48px;
    margin: 40px auto;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.loading:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    /* box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); */
}

.loading div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 12px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: transparent;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    perspective: 1000px;
    transform-origin: 100% 400%;
    overflow: hidden;
    animation: animate 4s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: calc(0.5s * var(--i));
    margin-left: 20px;
}
@keyframes animate {
    0% {
        transform: perspective(500px) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        opacity: 0.5;
        box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    25% {
        transform: perspective(500px) translate3d(-10px, -20px, 20px);
        opacity: 1;
        box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }
    35%,
    100% {
        transform: perspective(500px) translate3d(-10px, -20px, -150px);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
.loading div span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    /**background: url("/src/components/assets/images/blue-text-gradient.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;**/
}
```

For reference to the live site for inspection here is the link: [dekks](https://dekks.app/).
Also, feel free to correct me as this is my first time asking a question here.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at this example and modify you code accordingly.

```
<h1>
  <span>always be</span>
  <div class="message">
    <div class="word1">close</div>
    <div class="word2">code</div>
    <div class="word3">creating</div>
  </div>
</h1>
```

CSS

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
h1 {
  color: #333;
  font-family: tahoma;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 550px;
}

h1 span {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.message {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: #333;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 900;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
  top: 0.2rem;
  left: 270px;
  animation: openclose 5s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.word1, .word2, .word3 {
  font-family: tahoma;
}

@keyframes openclose {
  0% {
    top: 0.2rem;
    width: 0;
  }
  5% {
    width: 0;
  }
  15% {
    width: 230px;
  }
  30% {
    top: 0.2rem;
    width: 230px;
  }
  33% {
    top: 0.2rem;
    width: 0;
  }
  35% {
    top: 0.2rem;
    width: 0;
  }
  38% {
    top: -4.5rem;
    
  }
  48% {
    top: -4.5rem;
    width: 190px;
  }
  62% {
    top: -4.5rem;
    width: 190px;
  }
  66% {
    top: -4.5rem;
    width: 0;
    text-indent: 0;
  }
  71% {
    top: -9rem;
    width: 0;
    text-indent: 5px;
  }
  86% {
    top: -9rem;
    width: 285px;
  }
  95% {
    top: -9rem;
    width: 285px;
  }
  98% {
    top: -9rem;
    width: 0;
    text-indent: 5px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0;
    width: 0;
    text-indent: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, that does look like quite the animation. Unfortunately the designer I'm working with wants the animation to be as similar to the reference material as possible. If you don't mind I'd like to save this snippet of yours for future use. Again I appreciate your efforts, thank you so so much.